# Is streaming analytics framework like Apache spark or Apache storm suitable for IoT gateways?

Tags: node.js, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-storm, iot

I want the streaming analytics framework to be executed in IoT gateway itself instead of cloud server. The `Node.js` application, installed in gateway, listens for messages through a message broker ( `ZeroMQ` ) and does streaming analytics with a minimal latency.

Does `Node.js` support `Apache spark` or `Apache storm`?

The specification of IoT gateway is as follows:
1. **`CPU:`** Onboard single core 400MHz
2. **`MEM:`** DDR2 1GB
3. **`STORAGE:`** eMMC 4GB (expandable) 
4. **`OS:`** Ostro

If the mentioned frameworks are not supported, kindly suggest the alternatives.

Comment: Prem, after being 5 years a Memeber, you must already know and might want to update your post, so as to meet the StackOverflow policy to ask **`MCVE`** - related question and abstain from asking a subjective opinion based ***suggestions*** of whatever type on tools, products et al.

Comment: Next, your post mentions a **`ZeroMQ`** in a role of a broker. You might be interested in particular detail, one of the corner-stone `ZeroMQ` design maxims, input by it's wise fathers into this powerfull technology is to **be principally broker-less**.

Comment: Apache Storm and Apache Spark Streaming are distributed computing platforms and not streaming analytics frameworks.